# how to find MIME type of a image which has no extension?

Tags: node.js, image, mime

I am using Node.js server, and am saving images onto server with no file extension, (image name is just a number) is there any way to find out the MIME type of this kind of images? i need it as the browser is downloading the image instead of opening it in the browser.

I am using gm(GraphicsMagick) package to write text onto a image and am saving it into a folder without extensions. when i send this path via `res.sendFile('project root/uploads/cache/1')` , the browser doesn't understand its a image and downloads it, i want it to open it in the same tab

i also tried setting `image/*` , the browser just downloads the image, i am not sure if this kind of API can be consumed on React-Native app without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) as your file uploading middleware:

Router.js

```
multer  = require('multer'),

storage = multer.diskStorage({
    // Configuring multer to upload towards the public/uploads map
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'public/uploads')
    },
    // Rename the file, so we can create a reference to save in the database.
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        var ext = file.originalname.split('.')
        cb(null, 'upload-' + Date.now() + '.' + ext[ext.length - 1])
  }

})  

// Assign the configured storage to the upload.
upload = multer({ 
    storage: storage,
})
```

I configure my storage to rename all images (as multer does by default) into upload - Date.now() and the extension in the ext array. This way, the file gets saved with the extension, and automatically gives the following result:

[image: Example how it looks when uploaded]

Comment: I am Sorry i didnt mention this before, i am not using multer or any multipart form data, I am using gm(GraphicsMagick) package to write text onto a image and am saving it into a folder without extensions. when i send this path via `res.sendFile(__dirname+'/uploads/cache/1')` , the browser doesn't understand its a image and downloads it, i want it to open it in the same tab

Answer (score 1):

One approach, which have already been done for you in a library (I don't spend too much time in Node):  Create a map of file signatures to extensions, and query it with the first few hex digits of the uploaded file.

A good source of file signatures (a.k.a "magic numbers") and their extensions:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures